# SAPUI5 model filter: how to provide multiple AND conditions

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am using these filters in my app:

```
    filters: [
                    new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                        and: true,
                        filters: [
                            new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition1),
                            new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition2)
                        ]
                    }

                    ),
                    new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                        and: true,
                        filters: [
                            new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition3),
                            new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition4)
                        ]
                    }),
```

So this works like this:
give me all the data which satisfies -

**(condition1 AND condition2) OR (condition3 AND condition4)**

However, I want to do something like this:
give me all the data which satisfies -

**(condition1 AND condition2) AND (condition3 AND condition4)**

Is there any way to do that? I had tried this but it do not work somehow:

```
    filters: [
                    new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                        and: true,
                        filters: [
                            new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition1),
                            new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition2)
                        ]
                    }
                    and: true,  
                    ),
                    new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                        and: true,
                        filters: [
                            new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition3),
                            new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition4)
                        ]
                    }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AND is a transitive function, you can just go for

```
new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    and: true,
    filters: [
        new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition1),
        new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition2),
        new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition3),
        new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition4)
    ]
}
```

If you need to build your sub conditions separatly you can do it this way

```
var subCondition1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    and: true,
    filters: [
        new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition1),
        new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition2)
    ]
}

var subCondition2 = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    and: true,
    filters: [
        new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition3),
        new sap.ui.model.Filter(Filter condition4)
    ]
}

var finalCondition = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    and: true,
    filters: [
        subCondition1,
        subCondition2
    ]
}
```

(code not tested)